# Customizing layout programmatically

Tags: android, layout

I have a scrollable cardView, I can add new cards and customize its TextView values.

My card layout looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
       <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="625dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="24dp">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/card_title" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/cardBody"
                style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:text="@string/button" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top|end"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_bookmark_24dp"
            android:contentDescription="TODO" />

    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

i need to add chart inside the LinearLayout.
chart layout are written in seperate xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart
        android:id="@+id/chart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

So when I create a new card, I need to assign which chart belongs to it, I can imagine it as I have a placeholder inside my card where I can choose which chart will be displayed in it.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want a scrolling list of `CardViews`?

The proper way to add new `CardViews` would be with a `RecyclerView`, backing array, and a custom `Adapter`. The array would hold items of a custom class (call it `CardData`), with each object in this class containing all the necessary information to populate its corresponding `CardView`. The `RecyclerView` automatically inflates each `CardView` layout and populates its data based on the array.

Trying to add these things programmatically is a common beginner's mistake.